# Can i run liquibase database migrations after the app was initialized with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, migration, liquibase

**Context**

I am trying to start my spring app without a database(so when no database is available at initialization the app won't be stopped), i managed to do this with the following commands in app.prop:

```
#DB should not kill the app

spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true //app should continue if a sql init error arrises

spring.liquibase.enabled=false // liquibase bean shouldn't be initialized at start up, without this command the app crashes anyway

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Now the only thing that i need to do is figure a way so when the app does make a successful connection  with the db the liquibase migration files will get executed. For this task I understood I need to customize the liquibase bean, the following code shows my progress so far:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Value("${postgres.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${postgres.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${postgres.database}")
    private String database;

    @Value("${postgres.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${postgres.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.liquibase.change-log}")
    private String changelog;



    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(String.format("jdbc:postgresql://%s:%d/%s", host, port, database));
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase()  {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        liquibase.setChangeLog(changelog);
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

Preferably if the database is down the bean should not be created and if the database is running/ the server established connection with the db at some point the bean will be brought in the context and execute the migration files, i don't know if that is possible as I am a newbie,but let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: just a question, why would you start an application without database and then somehow hacky run the migration with additional liquibase migration? Everything is possible but I'm just wondering what would you like to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to achieve a spring boot application that will run if it has a database connected to it or if it doesn't, the purpose for this is that this connection will be displayed in a status json(this is out of context), also this is a job project and it doesn't make 100% sense for me either believe me. I can also show the stack trace error if it helps

Comment: how would you know that database was connected if application started without? Add as much details as you can it would be easier for others to help you.

Comment: I don't know how can you know when the db was connected to the app if it started without, but i think with the status json you would see if the db was up or down through the DataSource object you would get a connection from a pool if no exception gets thrown than it's ok if you get an exception is not ok, also i think a better question would be how to start spring boot app without a connection to db while also using liquibase, so i will close this question and open another